# How to use QueryDSL contains?

Tags: java, querydsl

I wonder how to use contains. I have a query

```
krystof.business.QNote note = krystof.business.QNote.note1;

        BooleanBuilder builder = new BooleanBuilder();

        for (Label savedLabel : existingLabels) {
            builder.and(note.labels.contains(savedLabel));

        }
```

Note:

```
class Note{
List<Label> labels;
}
```

Label

```
class Label{ 
String label;

@Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof Label)) return false;

        Label label1 = (Label) o;

        return getLabel() != null ? getLabel().equals(label1.getLabel()) : label1.getLabel() == null;
    } }
```

The existing query works and it is a predicate which checks if a note has 'savedLabel' among the the list of labels. 
Now I want to make a query which checks if a note has such a Label in its list, that Label.label.contains(someSubString).
The QueryDSL method `contains` takes a parameter Label child or Expression child but I don't know how to construct such an Expression. 
Thanks.